# Counting entries in a category using SAS functions first. and notsorted

Tags: sas, do-while, counting

I have some data which is broken down by Session and Activity, there being many sessions and within each session, many activities. What I would like to be able to do is to count the number of activities a person performs in each session (with times where a person performs the same activity at two separate times in a session counted separately). The data I am working with looks like this, with the count column being the one I want to create;

```
data have;     
  input Session $ Activity $ Count;
  datalines;
AAAA    VVVV    1
AAAA    XXXX    2
AAAA    XXXX    2
AAAA    YYYY    3
AAAA    ZZZZ    4
AAAA    XXXX    5
AAAA    XXXX    5
BBBB    VVVV    1
BBBB    XXXX    2
BBBB    YYYY    3
BBBB    YYYY    3
BBBB    YYYY    3
CCCC    VVVV    1
CCCC    VVVV    1
CCCC    XXXX    2
CCCC    XXXX    2
CCCC    YYYY    3
CCCC    ZZZZ    4
CCCC    VVVV    5
CCCC    XXXX    6
;
run;
```

I have managed to count the number of observations in each Session using this code;

```
proc sort
data = a.input;
by session eventtime;
run;

data a.example;
set a.input;
count +1;
if first.session then count =1;
by session eventtime;
tun;
```

I have been exploring this method using nested if statements along with the SAS first. function, however this seems to require the data to be sorted, which as an activity might occur at more than one points in a session I cannot do.

My first thoughts were to use a 'do' or 'do while' loop however I am not sure how to set the condition so that it iterates whilst an unknown value is constant.

Any help most appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post data for a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Not quite sure what eventtimes cover.

Comment: I thought someone would say that. I tried to post an example of the data but I can't get it to display correctly. How can I add a table into my question? Apologies for being a bit of a noob

Comment: Simply copy a few lines from data and paste in body and then code format `{}`. And don't worry, folks will come along to edit post if it comes out jumbled.

Comment: You don't need a table - just enter it in as datalines.  IE - `data have; input {variables}; datalines; ` and then one row per line of data, then `run;` .  (Put your actual variables in of course.)

Comment: @Taylrl I edited into the [tag:sas] tag info page (click on the link to get to it) an example of how to include `datalines`.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I ended up inputting it as code. Is what you can see in my question how it should look?

Comment: @Taylrl I edited in a `$` since session is character.  Can you also add a table `want` that describes what you want the final table to look like?  Or is `Count` the variable you're trying to create?

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I have also just edited it as in my data Activity is also a character. And yes, the variable I am trying to create is {Count}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the `count` variable calculated, then you should be able to do it like this.  `by` does *not* require sorting:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by session activity notsorted;
  if first.session then new_count=0;
  if first.activity then new_count+1;
run;
```

This assumes it's sorted the way you want it (by event time) going into this dataset.  `notsorted` tells `by` not to worry about the actual sort order; `first` now detects changes from the previous value only.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. That looks excellent and makes sense to me. It is also quite similar to some of the things I had been playing around with. I knew it would be something simple in the end. Thanks again!